# Count returns 0 if no rows found

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, return-value

This is the code on sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9596d/8

```
create table tbla (uid nvarchar(10), name nvarchar(50));
create table tblb (uid nvarchar(10), cd nvarchar(5));

insert into tbla values ('abc','abraham lincoln');
insert into tbla values ('def','david copperfield');
insert into tblb values ('abc','a');
insert into tblb values ('abc','b');
insert into tblb values ('abc','c');
insert into tblb values ('def','a');
insert into tblb values ('def','c');
```

I need to return the count. And return 0 if no records found. This is what I have, but it doesn't return 0 for *uid* **def**

```
select a.uid, a.name, count(b.cd) as ct
from tblb b
left join
tbla a
on b.uid = a.uid
where b.cd = 'b'
group by a.uid, a.name
```

What am I doing wrong? It's using outer join.

Comment: Your where clause filters it out beforehand. Instead of a where clause you could use a CASE WHEN inside the count.

Answer (score 2):

You had your tables backwards for a left join, and you need to use the join clause instead of the `where` clause for conditions on the `left join` table. Otherwise you are turning your `left join` into an `inner join`.

```
select a.uid, a.name, count(b.cd) as ct
from tbla a
  left join tblb b
    on b.uid = a.uid
   and b.cd = 'b'
group by a.uid, a.name
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZXBS56241

returns:

```
+-----+-------------------+----+
| uid |       name        | ct |
+-----+-------------------+----+
| abc | abraham lincoln   |  1 |
| def | david copperfield |  0 |
+-----+-------------------+----+
```

Comment: Thank you. It does work on restester.com and sqlfiddle. However, it doesn't look like it works on SQL Server Management Studio whichever way it goes. Know why?

Comment: There must be something different about your implementation, as this works on http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7fe7ad20cd9340e5d6bf198dc276f839 and also in sql server management studio https://gyazo.com/845f10946caf5b7de94a153f33b28d08

Comment: Yes, I apologize. It does work; I just set up the sample incorrectly. Just corrected the it and was not able to edit my earlier comments. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this correct way of doing it,

```
create table #tbla (uid nvarchar(10), name nvarchar(50));
create table #tblb (uid nvarchar(10), cd nvarchar(5));

insert into  #tbla values ('abc','abraham lincoln');
insert into  #tbla values ('def','david copperfield');
insert into  #tblb values ('abc','a');
insert into  #tblb values ('abc','b');
insert into  #tblb values ('abc','c');
insert into  #tblb values ('def','a');
insert into  #tblb values ('def','c');

--select * from  #tblb
--select * from  #tbla
;With CTE as
(
select b.uid,  count(b.cd) as ct
from #tblb b
where b.cd = 'b'
group by b.uid
)
select a.uid,isnull(c.ct,0),a.name from #tbla a
left join cte c  on 
a.uid=c.uid 

drop table #tblb
drop table #tbla
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a great solution as well.